# JD Edwards EnterpriseOne - Any way to include Branch Plant in processInventoryItem Business Service

Tags: oracle, web-services, jdedwards, enterpriseone

I am working on an integration from a software product to JD Edwards EnterpriseOne, and we would like to create items that would later be used on Sales Orders. The issue arises when attempting to create a sales order with an item that was created via the business service (web service), it requires the item to be added to a branch/plant.

There is no field on the processInventoryItem request message to set the branch plant for the newly created item -- is there any way to do this via the API and not need to custom-build a new business service which includes it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Which JDE version you are using? And which Business Service are you calling to create an item?

Comment: It is EnterpriseOne 9.1. Trying to use processInventoryItem method of the InventoryManager business service.

Answer (score 0):

You could use *processInventoryItemV2* to create the Item Branch after Item Master creation.

According to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E16582_01/doc.91/e38040.pdf):

> The processInventoryItemV2 operation is a version of the processInventoryItem web 
>   service operation. This web service operation is used to add, update, and delete 
>   branch plant item records along with country of origin required indicator. This version 
>   executes the processInventoryItem (J4100003) web service operation.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to highlight a relevant issue and work around implemented, which my be of help.

We have a business requirement where a manufacturing plant sends a new product to a branch plant which is not handling the product hitherto.

We worked around by creating an overnight scheduler which creates item branch record for the receiving B/P for the new item.